# Linux Mint 17.2 encounters an error, remounts disk in readonly

Tags: linux-mint, cron, alsa, readonly

I already posted the question actually ([Linux Mint 17.2 suddenly loses write access to filesystem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245065/linux-mint-17-2-suddenly-loses-write-access-to-filesystem)), but since it occurs rarely I need to ask again with some new info I gathered.

I suspect that this error somehow related to `cron` activities and/or audio card driver. Every time it happens, one of the last entries in logs is about `cron` and today there was some about audio driver. Here it is:

> 12/22/15 10:17:01 AM  duat-re-P55A-UD3    CRON[2824]  (root) CMD (   cd /
>   && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
>
> 12/22/15 10:17:34
>   AM    duat-re-P55A-UD3    pulseaudio[2501]    [alsa-sink-ctxfi] alsa-sink.c:
>   ALSA woke us up to write new data to the device, but there was
>   actually nothing to write!
>
> 12/22/15 10:17:34
>   AM    duat-re-P55A-UD3    pulseaudio[2501]    [alsa-sink-ctxfi] alsa-sink.c:
>   Most likely this is a bug in the ALSA driver 'snd_ctxfi'. Please
>   report this issue to the ALSA developers.
>
> 12/22/15 10:17:34
>   AM    duat-re-P55A-UD3    pulseaudio[2501]    [alsa-sink-ctxfi] alsa-sink.c: We
>   were woken up with POLLOUT set -- however a subsequent snd_pcm_avail()
>   returned 0 or another value < min_avail.

So can somebody guess what should I do to get rid of this error?

Comment: Can you post your `dmesg` output to pastebin? I think these cron & audio messages have nothing with what symptoms you have.

Comment: I will when it happens again. I'm not sure whether I can provoke it but I'm gonna try.

Comment: @siblynx, here you go http://pastebin.com/K2syzKVi

Answer (score 1):

http://pastebin.com/K2syzKVi: Given that you have a few EXT4-fs error's, you should run a `e2fsck -f /dev/sda5` when the partition is offline (unmounted). If it's your root partition, then run a LiveCD/USB and run it from there. In short, you have filesystem errors on your /dev/sda5.

Comment: I tried to do so and it seems `e2fsck` didn't find any errors. Just as `gparted`. Is it really FS problem? Is there some other way to fix it?

Comment: If `e2fsck` didn't found any errors and your dmesg still emits _this_ error message, then there maybe a ext4 kernel bug. In 17.2 I remember kernel version is 4.2.x. But if there are more different errors you did not seen before, then this is possible sign of drive failure.